# Trouble Adding Markers to Google Maps via Ajax

Tags: ajax, google-maps, google-maps-markers

What I am trying to achieve:

1. Generate Map
2. Get Bounds information for Map
3. Make Ajax call passing Bounds information, data returned is Marker info
4. Populate Map with Markers

I am stuck because I cannot get the Ajax call to trigger.

The code seems to stop running after the alert("ajax ready").  I have a breakpoint on my controller action which never gets hit.

The only error I am getting is that "nE is undefined", however if I put in an alert the line after I am setting the value, then the the value is shown, so am not even sure that is relevant.

I have worked successfully with an earlier version of Google Maps, V3 seems a bit different.  I couldn't get the lines of code to set the bounds to run until they were placed in an event listener.  I tried the same with the Ajax call but doesn't make a difference.

I do know that I am not adding the markers to the map within the ajax call, I have yet to get to that part.

Javascript:

```
function initMap() {

var markers = [];

 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('local-map'), {
    center: { lat: 51.509865, lng: -0.118092 },
    zoom: 15
});
 var bounds = undefined;
 var nE = undefined;
 var sW = undefined;

 google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function () {
     bounds = map.getBounds();
     nE = bounds.getNorthEast();
     sW = bounds.getSouthWest();
 });

alert("ajax ready");
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/Home/GetMapMarkers',
    data: { neLatitude: nE.lat(), neLongitude: ne.lng(), swLatitude: sW.lat(), swLongitude: sW.lng() }
}).done(function (data) {

    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
    {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(data[i].Latitude, data[i].Longitude),
            map: map,
            title: data[i].RestaurantName
        });
        markers.push(marker);
    }

});

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "bounds_changed" listener will fire asynchronously when the map bounds changes.  You need to put your AJAX call **inside** its callback function (when/where the new bounds is available):

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function () {
   bounds = map.getBounds();
   nE = bounds.getNorthEast();
   sW = bounds.getSouthWest();

  alert("ajax ready");
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/Home/GetMapMarkers',
    data: { neLatitude: nE.lat(), neLongitude: ne.lng(), swLatitude: sW.lat(), swLongitude: sW.lng() }
    }).done(function (data) {
      for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
      {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(data[i].Latitude, data[i].Longitude),
          map: map,
          title: data[i].RestaurantName
        });
        markers.push(marker);
      }
    });
});
```